# A simpler proof for a probability problem

Tags: probability, statistics, stochastic-processes, conditional-probability, order-statistics

I am trying to prove the following lemma 2.3.5 from Stochastic Processes, Sheldon Ross, 2nd ed, page 77 which I have provided it here for convenience. The proof is provided in the book based on a lemma before this lemma whose proof is very messy. I believe there must be a simpler proof for the main lemma which will not depend on the other lemma.[image]

I am trying to prove it for $n=3$. I really appreciate any idea and help in this regard.

Comment: one way to cope with it is that, for $n=3$, we fix $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ and we find the probability and then we take expectation with respect to joint dist. of $(\tau_1, \tau_2)$